# CoreData(MagicalRecord) getting saved objects

Tags: ios, database, core-data, magicalrecord

I have structure with entity 'wall post', it has same structured entity 'repost'. They have relationships ( 'wall post' have 'repost' with Destination as 'wall post' and inverse as 'repost').

Now I am getting objects with code

```
     NSArray *newsEntities = [[NSArray alloc] init];
     newsEntities = [WallpostEntity findAllSortedBy:@"pubDate" ascending:NO];
```

I have WallpostEntity and reposts in array. How can I get only 'wall posts'?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of that you're getting two different types of entities on this fetch request is that you've modeled your WallPost Entity to be a base class of Repost. That is, Repost is a subclass of Wallpost. If you only want Wallposts returned from your request, then you need to modify your code like so:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [WallpostEntity MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"pubDate" ascending:NO];
[request setIncludesSubEntities:NO];
newsEntities = [WallpostEntity MR_executeRequest:request];
```